# Indicator function sign

Tags: packages, math-operators, mathematics, mathbb

Whenever I need the indicator function I use (for example) the following syntax

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\Huge The indicator function : 
$$ \mathbb 1_A (x) = 
\begin{cases}
1\hspace{0.5cm} \text{if } x\in A\\
0\hspace{0.5cm} \text{if } x\notin A
\end{cases}
$$\end{document}
```

The problem is that the command `mathbb 1_A`or more specifically `mathbb 1` returns a weird sign that almost resembles the indicator function :

[image]

Is there any package that I should add ? Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

```
\begin{document}
%>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
\[
  \mathbf {1} _{A}(x):=
  \begin{cases}1~&{\text{ if }}~x\in A~,\\0~&{\text{ if }}~x\notin A~.\end{cases}\]
%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```

[image: indicatrice]

Comment: The output here is the number one in bold. I'm looking for the number one in the $\mathbb$ type, just like the real number set $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The typography rule is  bold. Follow the specified links upwards for blackboard fonts which are supposed to be used on blackboards and not for printed texts.

Comment: Hmmm, in my context matrices are boldface, and there is a vector of ones that I typeset as $\mathbf{1}$. Is there an alternative notation for the indicator that is preferred to $\mathbb{1}$?